# Dart Polymer core-splitter: drag/resize event

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, core-elements

Is there any stream I can listen to that fires when a core-splitter is moved? I've tried the following:

Html:

```dart
<div id="left-div"></div>
<core-splitter direction="left"></core-splitter>
<div id="right-div"></div>
```

Dart:

```dart
initPolymer().run(() {
  Polymer.onReady.then((_) {   
    querySelector('#left-div').onResize.listen((_) => print('resizing left'));
    querySelector('#right-div').onResize.listen((_) => print('resizing right'));
    querySelector('core-splitter').onDrag.listen((_) => print('dragging'));
  });
});
```

The page runs, but nothing is ever printed.

More generally, is there a way to listen for an element resizing due to an unspecified parent element's resize event? For example, if I had a div nested inside the left div, is there an easy way I can listen to changes to the inner divs size without explicitly attaching it to the movement of the splitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation doesn't mention any events for `core-splitter`. I guess events similar to the ones `paper-slider` https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-slider has got recently were a good fit for `core-splitter` as well.

You can create a feature request at https://github.com/Polymer/core-splitter/issues

Answer (score 1):

frankiefu from github provided an elegant solution. There is a 'track' event that can be listened to via addEventListener

```
querySelector('core-splitter').addEventListener('track', callback);
```

You can see a working js version [here](http://jsbin.com/pototenowo/1/edit?html,console,output), though the script is almost identical in dart.